# Second Order Differential Equation - finding maximum and minimum values of particular integrals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

Given that $y$ = $\frac{3}{4}\cos3x + \frac{1}{4}\sin3x$ is a particular integral of the differential equation
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+ 4\frac{dy}{dx}+13y = 6 \cos3x-8\sin3x$$
how do I show that $\frac{\sqrt{10}}{4}$ and $\frac{-\sqrt{10}}{4}$ are maximum and minimum values of the particular integral?

Please explain the method as I am trying to self learn and getting stuck with this particular question.

So far I have tried differentiating, integrating and solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}= 0$ but I keep getting an answer of $\arctan(n),$ where $\arctan(n) \neq$ $\frac{\sqrt{10}}{4}$ or $\frac{-\sqrt{10}}{4}$

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The arctan will not involve $\sqrt{10}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to maximize, minimize $3\cos 3x+\sin 3x$. If we really want to use the calculus, differentiate and set the derivative equal to $0$. We get $\tan{3x}=\frac{1}{3}$. Using a triangle, or $\sec^2 3x=\tan^2 3x +1$, we get $\cos^2 3x=\frac{9}{10}$ so $\cos 3x=\pm \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} $ and $\sin 3x=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$. (The two plus go together, as do the two minus.)

**Another way:** Let $\theta$ be an angle whose sine is $\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$ and whose cosine is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$. Then our original function is 
$$\frac{\sqrt{10}}{4}\sin(\theta+3x).$$
Maximizing/minimizing is now easy, for the max. value of $\sin t$ is $1$, and the min value of $\sin t$ is $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Find the derivative of $y = \frac{3}{4} \cos3x + \frac{1}{4} \sin3x$
- Set $y' = 0$ to find the critical points. You have:

$$y' = \dfrac{3}{4} \cos 3x - \dfrac{9}{4} \sin 3x = 0 \rightarrow \tan 3x = \dfrac{1}{3}$$

- Find the values of $x$ that satisfies that equation.
- Test those values for min and max.

A plot shows:

[image]